# How can I remove incomplete installation of Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: uninstall

I was trying to install Ubuntu 13.04 alongside with my Windows 8.1. But after the completion of installation, I logged in 1 time only. When I was logged in again to Ubuntu, the display was only blinking.

So I tried to install Ubuntu again from CD but the problem remains. Then I tried to install it through Windows but the same. Then I tried to delete Ubuntu partition through Windows, now my Windows as well as Ubuntu is not working. How can I fix this with Ubuntu live booting?

EDIT: Now I can access Windows but Ubuntu is just blinking as before. Can I uninstall Ubuntu?

Comment: Dont worry along with ubuntu u deleted grub.. reinstalling ubuntu just like u did before will solve your problem..both windows and Linux will boot just install Linux again inside free space

Comment: Now i can access windows bu the ubuntu is just blinking  as bfr.can inuninstall ubuntu ?

Comment: 13.04? why? Please install a supported release

Answer (score 1):

To dual boot your machine Ubuntu needs some unallocated disk space.

Open disk management, select any big disk and right click, then select option **shrink volume**, type 70000MB (that's enough to run smoothly) and hit <kbd>enter</kbd>. You will get a black area as unallocated. Now make a bootable pendrive of Ubuntu, shut down your system, boot your pendrive using boot key and select USB. Select **Install Ubuntu**

You will get an option **Install Ubuntu alongside Windows**, which you should select. This should install Ubuntu on your system (make sure both operating systems are in UEFI mode (or both in Legacy mode - check the BIOS or UEFI settings if unsure). If this option doesn't appear then choose the **Something else** option and you will have to manually partition unallocated space (sample images attached here)

[image: Windows disk management]

[image: preferred option is install alongside - choose Something Else for manual partitioning]

[image: partition set up example]

[image: partition type dialog]

[image: partitioning dialogs]

[image: partitioning]

[image: partitioning]

Continue installation...reboot after completion.. hope this helps :)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; the entire conversation that was taking place here has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45706/discussion-on-answer-by-sardapv-how-can-i-remove-incomplete-installation-of-ubun).

Answer (score 0):

It is *not possible* to uninstall an operating system, you can only overwrite it or remove its partition. However, your problem is caused by [bootloaders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booting#Modern_boot_loaders). During Ubuntu installation, the Windows bootloader is replaced with [GRUB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB) which partly resides on the Linux partition. Therefore it stops working when you remove Ubuntu partition.

So what you need is to **restore Windows bootloader**. Then you can remove the Ubuntu partition safely. I haven’t done it for Windows 8.1 yet, so I cannot give exact advice. Moreover, the procedure may vary depending whether you use legacy [BIOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS) or [UEFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface) and [MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) or [GPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table).

First of all, prepare the Windows recovery/install media. Then follow a guide like this one: http://www.fixedbyvonnie.com/2013/12/how-to-repair-the-efi-bootloader-in-windows-8/

Or try a newer Ubuntu version to see if your graphics problem is fixed.